# Magento 1.8.0.0 OneStepCheckout not submitting note/comments if paypal Express was chosen

Tags: magento, paypal, onestepcheckout

I got a problem with a Magento 1.8 store. The shop has installed OneStepCheckout. Inside of the extension it can be set two fields
-> "how did you hear about us"
-> "Comments"

Strange thing is everytime "paypal" is selected both values do not get send to magento. They do not show up in backend in order details.

Does someone has the same problem? and how to fix it?

Comment: update your OneStepCheckout  to latest . Paypal express is different checkout method direct posted variables will not survive. In latest OneStepCheckout those variables are carried trough quote so will be carried over to other checkout methods as well.